# loop for + zendFramework

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this loop "for" in my script

```
   function (respond) {

    var json=JSON.stringify(respond);
    var objet = eval('(' + json + ')');
    for ( var count = 0 ; count <objet.length  ; count++ ) { 
    jQuery("#SubCategory").empty().append("<option value='" + count + "'>" + objet[count].name+ "</option>"); 
    }
 }
```

the editer emphasizes `objet.length  ;`  objet.length is the number of objects in the array object "objet".

can you please help me.

Comment: then it means your eval doesn't return objects

Comment: here is what i got when i do console.log(objet);     [Object { name="Women's Clothing"}, Object { name="Mens's Clothing"}, Object { name="kid's Clothing"}]. even when i write  count < 3 it emphasizes objet.length ;

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
objet = [{name :"Womens Clothes"}, {name: "Mens Clothes"}, {name: "Kids Clothes"}];
console.log(objet)
objet.length;
for ( var count = 0 ; count <objet.length; count++ ) { 
       alert(objet[count].name);
    }
```

change variable names, really confusing

maybe you need this instead if using jquery

```
try
            {

                data = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                if (typeof data.id === undefined) {
                      throw "Err1";
                    }
            }
            catch(err)
            {
...
            }
```

Comment: thank you max4ever                                                                    I find a solution to my problem here is the code

    function (respond) {

   var json=JSON.stringify(respond);
   var  objet = eval('(' + json + ')');

      e=objet.length;

      var str = "";

    for ( var count = 0 ; count < e; count++ ) { 

        str += "<option value='" + count + "'>" + objet[count].name+ "</option>"
    } 

     $("#SubCategory").empty().append(""+str);
 }

Answer (score 0):

If you will use below code, it will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var respond = [{name :"Womens Clothes"}, {name: "Mens Clothes"}, {name: "Kids Clothes"}];
    var objet = eval(respond);

    for( var count = 0 ; count < objet.length; count++ ) { 
        alert(count + " -- " + objet[count].name);
    }
</script>
```

You need not to use both "stringify" and "eval" as it works similarly.

Thanks